# Prove that $(\log(n))^k=O(n)$ for any $k$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I'm having problem proving that $(\log(n))^k=O(n)$. I tried googling it but can't find an answer.

Comment: An alternate statement is: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log n)^k}{n} = 0$$  Can you do that?

Comment: @GEdgar Not really

Comment: To help you realize just how slowly $\log^k(n)$ grows compared to $n$, look at the monoticaly increasing subsequence $a_n=e^n$, and compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log^k(a_n)/a_n$.

Comment: Okey but how do I prove that (log(n))k=O(n) for any k

Comment: @Y0ungboi He just told you...

Answer (score 2):

$\log n = O(n^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, since
$$\log n = \tfrac1\epsilon \log(n^\epsilon) = \tfrac1\epsilon\textstyle\int_1^{n^\epsilon}\frac{dt}{t} <\tfrac1\epsilon \int_1^{n^\epsilon}dt= \tfrac1\epsilon n^\epsilon-\tfrac1\epsilon < \tfrac1\epsilon n^\epsilon,$$

Thus $\log^kn= O(n^{k\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Let $\epsilon=1/k$ and you're done.

Comment: Proof: $\ln(n) = \int_1^n dt/t < \int_1^n dt = n-1$.

Comment: @martycohen nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Without lost of generality let me consider $\ln$ in place of $\log$. Having $\frac{(\ln n)}{n}^k=\left( \frac{\ln n}{n^{1/k}} \right)^k$ is enough to consider

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^{1/k}} =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{k}n^{\frac{1}{k}-1}}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{k}{n^{1/k}} = 0$$